# Listview filter through same names Android

Tags: java, android

So I have a custom spinner header, where the user can change the title of names based on selection. What I want to do is if they click on the spinner and change the default, then it only shows the names in the listview from the title of names. Currently I have tried this by reinstantiating my fragment from my tabhost, and if conditions are met it would just remove from list everything that doesnt have what user selected. But this is inefficient and it didn't work as the listview wasn't updated and the condition wasn't even getting called on the new instantiation... Is there any filter way I can do for this? Any ideas or help would be great!

Comment: Can you post your code, please? The code that defines and populates the Spinner (and any Adapter) would be helpful.

Comment: The thing is.. if you read I am really not looking for that solution. I am looking for possibly a way to filter the listview based on changing the spinner text.

Comment: Um, yeah, I was going somewhere with that. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to refresh the `ListView` not the entire fragment. There are several ways to do this, including providing a different data source to the `ListView`'s adapter. The exact details for how to do this depend on whether you are using an `ArrayAdapter` or a `CursorAdapter`.

Comment: I am using a Base adapter for reading in model information. The thing is everything is separate since its all on a tabhost swipe view, so I would need to recall the fragment to load the new data? Maybe I am wrong. Maybe you can provide an example.

Comment: @codewarrior You shouldn't need to reload the whole fragment. You should only give a new data set to the `ListView`.

Comment: @codewarrior Are you implementing your own custom class which extends `BaseAdapter`?

Comment: Yea because i am listing custom data

Comment: @codewarrior Then all you need to do is provide a new list of data to your adapter class. Or have your adapter filter the existing list.

Comment: Yea im creating a filter class now with my listview. But i like your idea.. would i just pass the new list in and then how would i update on the main ui so it changes

Comment: @codewarrior I suggest adding a method to your adapter class which filters the list rather than passing the filtered list from somewhere else. To refresh the UI, you simply call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on your adapter.

Comment: So i would recreate the adapter in the activity even tho i tho i have in the fragment that is originally getting called.

Comment: @codewarrior It would be better to hold a reference to the original adapter rather than recreating a new adapter each time. I'm not sure whether it is better to hold this reference in the activity or in one (or more) of your fragments. These details depend on your current design as well as considerations about which classes need access to the adapter.

Comment: So just make a global viewholder for the original listview? And ill be good?

Comment: @codewarrior I'm not sure what you mean by "global viewholder". The word "global" makes me cringe. Again, the details depend on your current design.

Comment: Makes me cringe too. Didnt mean it like that. Thks i think i got the logic down